# Why does login redirect fail in MVC when using a FormsAuthentication CustomIdentity and updating AuthTicket UserData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-membershipprovider

Using forms authentication, I am filling the `UserData` field with a serialized `CustomIdentitySerializer` object.

The user logs in, and I have verified that `Membership.ValidateUser()` works just fine.

I then begin populating the `CustomIdentitySerializer` object and send it off to a static `UpdateAuthenticationTicket` method in a static `UserContext` class to test data retention - After Login() / `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated:`

```
// set auth ticket
UserContext.UpdateAuthenticationTicket(user.Username, serializeModel);

// get custom identity - user properties
string userName = UserContext.Identity.UserName;

// reset login attempts
Session["_LoginAttempts"] = 0;

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
```

Helper method:

```
/// <summary>
/// As we will want to update the UserData portion of the cookie while the 
/// user is logged, this will be reused
/// 
/// Auth Ticket/Cookie's UserData property is the CustomIdentitySerializer object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userName"></param>
/// <param name="userData"></param>
public static void UpdateAuthenticationTicket(string userName, CustomIdentitySerializer userData)
{
    //var authUser = GetUser(userName);
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string userDataSerialized = serializer.Serialize(userData);

    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
        userName,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
        false,
        userDataSerialized,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        // encrypt the ticket
        string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

        // create/set the cookie
        HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);

    }
```

`userData` can change through the user's time on the site, so we will reuse this method whenever that data needs to be changed.

In `Global.asax.cs` I have:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        var fromsIdentity = new FormsIdentity(authTicket);

        // Get the GenericPrincipal identity  
        IIdentity ui = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;  

        CustomIdentity customIdentity = new CustomIdentity(ui.Name);
        CustomPrincipal customPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal(ui.Name);

        string userData = ((FormsIdentity)(Context.User.Identity)).Ticket.UserData;

        // Set custom principal 
        HttpContext.Current.User = customPrincipal;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Since we set current project and other custom user fields  through the user experience,
/// these are saved in the authticket/cookie's UserData field as a CustomIdentitySerializer object type
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            // get the current cookie
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            var fromsIdentity = new FormsIdentity(authTicket);
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            CustomIdentitySerializer userData = serializer.Deserialize<CustomIdentitySerializer>(authTicket.UserData);

            CustomPrincipal customPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            customPrincipal.CustomIdentity.FirstName = userData.FirstName;
            customPrincipal.CustomIdentity.LastName = userData.LastName;
            customPrincipal.CustomIdentity.CurrentProject = userData.CurrentProject;

            HttpContext.Current.User = customPrincipal;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this may have to do with the Principal provider not being set properly or rewritten.

After the cookie value is set, `Application_AuthenticateRequest` get's hit, followed by `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`.  This process occurs twice, then back to the Login page.

It seems that the code in `Application_AuthenticateRequest` is not useful, as I'm not setting any properties there anyway.

The problem is that after the user is actually logged in, the `RedirectToAction` goes back to `http://localhost:1982/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fDashboard` rather than appropriate page.

Are there any foreseeable issues in having updating the cookie from the static `UserContext` class?

Some assistance on this please on how to clean this up and getting working?

Thanks.

**-- UPDATE --**

In looking at the `authCookie` object in `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`, `Expires` is set to `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`.  Regardless, the `authTicket` cookie expiration is correct - 30 minutes from time of creation.  So that cookie is there.

What else?

**-- UPDATE --**

In looking at the cookie version, I notice a difference.  As soon as I set the cookie in `UpdateAuthenticationTicket`, I check:

```
authTicket.Version =
```

and

FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Version = 2

Not sure why there are two versions, if someone can please explain that as well?  I tried setting the cookie with version=2 - same issue.

Comment: Have you verified that the cookie is getting set (by checking response cookies) and sent to the browser (by checking what the browser has for cookies)?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the default cookie name `.ASPXAUTH` is being set - I see it in the browser.  I am setting it with `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);`

Comment: In `UpdateAuthenticationTicket` I also added          'FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);' - no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In further messing around with this, I moved the code over from `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` to `Application_AuthenticateRequest` and everything seems to work fine now:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            // get the current cookie
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            var fromsIdentity = new FormsIdentity(authTicket);
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            CustomPrincipal customPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            CustomIdentitySerializer userData = serializer.Deserialize<CustomIdentitySerializer>(authTicket.UserData);
            if (userData != null)
            {
                customPrincipal.CustomIdentity.FirstName = userData.FirstName;
                customPrincipal.CustomIdentity.LastName = userData.LastName;
                customPrincipal.CustomIdentity.CurrentProject = userData.CurrentProject;
            }

            HttpContext.Current.User = customPrincipal;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why this is, as so many of the references I have found for this indicate to put this code in `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`???